# How to compile .asm file with a public procedure

Tags: assembly

I developed a C function that calls an Assembly 8086 public procedure. Now I want to generate the exe, and I know I have to call this commands:

```
gcc -c main.c
nasm -f coff myasm.asm
gcc -o myexe.exe myasm.o main.o
```

The problem is that the second command doesn't work, because I get these errors about the initial public _procedurename row in ASM file. How should I compile this particular file? Thank you!

```
myasm.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
myasm.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected
```

And here you are my first and second row, the ones with errors

```
public _countweeks
.MODEL SMALL, C
```

Comment: Is this really NASM syntax? Also, you can't use 16 bit assembly in a 32 bit program.

Comment: `.MODEL SMALL C` looks an awful lot like a MASM directive, not NASM